# PHP illegal string offset error & string conversion errors

Tags: php, mysql

I know there has been a few questions like this one but I can't seem to fix my code using any of the answers I've seen. 
I'm using version 5.6.15 of PHP and I'm pulling my information from my PHPMYADMIN database. The table I'm trying to use is called university and the primary key of that table is 'UNI_ID'. It says it's an array when I used var_dump but I can't work out how to convert it to a string or even if that's what I need to do. 
The 'delete' and 'edit' buttons are the ones that are causing the error as the error is for those lines. I'm also getting an array to string conversion error too. 
I've tried using isset but it still doesn't work. 
This appears to work fine on another page with the same code on there, just can't find the difference.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
      $sql="SELECT * FROM university";
      $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


      while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
      {
        echo "<table border='' width='100%'><tr><td width='75%'><b><a href=university.php?=UNI_ID".$row=["UNI_ID"].">".$row["Name"]."</b></td>".
        "<td><img src=images/".$row["Logo"]." width= '25px' ></td></tr>".
        "<tr><td><b>City: </b>".$row["Location"]."</td>".
        "<td><b>Rank: </b>".$row["Ranking"]."</td></tr>";
        if(isset($_SESSION["Email"])){
            if($_SESSION["Admin"] == "1"){
                echo "<tr><td><input type=\"button\" value=\"Delete\" onClick=\"window.location.href='deleteuni.php?=UNI_ID".$row["UNI_ID"]."'\">".
                "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Edit\" onClick=\"window.location.href='edituniform.php?=UNI_ID".$row["UNI_ID"]."'\"></td></tr></table>";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "</table>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Typo: `$row=["UNI_ID"]`.

Comment: Looks like a typo in your `href`s: change `?=UNI_ID` to `?UNI_ID=`.

Comment: @AlinPurcaru Yes, that has worked now. Thank you very much. I can't believe I've spent this long on such a stupid mistake!

Comment: Happens to everyone. Take a break when you can't figure out. Watch a cat video on youtube. It definitely helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a typo in your code:

```
$row=["UNI_ID"]
```

Where you probably meant to have:

```
$row["UNI_ID"]
```

Now to explain what happens with the typo present, as it is a bit interesting. You would expect a syntax error maybe, but because you have PHP > 5.4, it's (almost) valid code.

- `["UNI_ID"]` will create you a numerically indexed array with a single string in it. Equivalent to `array(0 => "UNI_ID")`.
- next, that newly create array gets concatenated with what follows after it until the `;`, becoming a useless monster string and throwing that conversion Notice in the process because you concatenated an array to a string. But a Notice error is low level, so it doesn't stop the script, it goes on.
- it then assigns that monster string to your *$row* completely changing it into a string instead of the array you had before. And next time you try to get something from *$row* you get the string offset error(s), because strings can be accessed like arrays, but only for some keys, and the ones you try to get are definitely not in it. So again, no critical error, and the script goes on.

This goes to show that PHP is not such a great language, because it allows you to end up with typos like this that only trigger Notices.

Comment: Have you typo'd the *Where you probably meant to have:*, I'm guessing that was meant to be `$row["UNI_ID"]` :p

Comment: @Pigeon Corrected. Thank you!